Zeeman splitting of a spectral line in the presence of a strong magnetic field as compared to that of a magnetic field of intermediate strength
Will the number of spectral lines into which a spectral line will split due to an electronic transition from a P state with spin=1/2 to a S state with spin=1/2 be more in the presence of a strong magnetic field as compared to a magnetic field of intermediate strength ?
I am aware that using the selection rules $\Delta m_{j} = 0,+1,-1$ ($\ m_j=0 $ to $\ m_j=0$  transition only when $\Delta J=0 $ ; where $\ j = \mid l-s \mid to \mid l+s \mid$) one can calculate the allowed transitions. But what i am unable to understand is that how the magnetic field strength affects the above mentioned selection rules governing the number of lines into which a spectral line is split.
It would be very helpful if the explanation is based on the particular case which i have mentioned above.
Thanks in advance.

The total number of lines corresponding to Zeeman splitting will not change as $B$ increases because it is governed only by the number of different states that the spin has, which for an electron with $s = 1/2$ is 2 (-1/2 and +1/2). However, the energy separation of the different angular momentum states does change when $B$ increases. Particularly when the magnetic interactions become comparable to orbital energies, the electronic structure changes completely.

Is it the case that for strong field Zeeman effect all the degeneracies of the system are removed completely compared to the case of weak field Zeeman effect. Also in the case of strong field Zeeman effect would the total angular momentum quantum number J be still a good quantum number ?
